# What is wrong with this shell command

Tags: bash, shell, rvm

I need to add this to `.bashrc`

```
echo '[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

but i am using a shell script and i need to run this under another user so i tried the following..

```
BASH_COMMAND='[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"'
sudo su ${USER} -c "echo '${BASH_COMMAND}' >> ${HOME_BASE}${USER}/.bashrc"
```

I was expecting to see

```
'[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

in my `.bashrc`

but i see this instead

```
sudo su ${USER} -c "echo echo 'sudo su ${USER} -c "echo '${BASH_COMMAND}' >> ${HOME_BASE}${USER}/.bashrc"' >> /home/deploy/.bashrc >> ${HOME_BASE}${USER}/.bashrc"
```

What am i doing wrong with the script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

shell can sometimes misinterpret redirection, you can overcome this with:

```
RVM_COMMAND='[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"'
echo "${RVM_COMMAND}" | sudo su ${USER} -c 'tee -a "$HOME/.bashrc"' >/dev/null
```